# Programmatically Adding Nodes to a JsTree

Tags: javascript, jstree, nodes

I've been doing some troubleshooting and haven't been able to do what I thought would be a fairly simple operation, adding a node to a jstree programmatically.  Currently I've been attempting to do this in the simplest way I can imagine:

```
$('#irrigationClimateStations')
.jstree({
    'plugins' : ['themes', 'json_data', 'ui', 'crrm'],
    'json_data': {
        "data" : [
            { 
                "data" : "A node", 
                "metadata" : { id : 23 },
                "children" : [ "Child 1", "A Child 2" ]
            }
        ]
    },
    'themes': {
        'theme': 'weather'
    }
});
```

The tree is created successfully, but when I attempt to add another node, nothing happens (and I receive no errors from jstree):

```
var newNode = {
    'attr' : { 'id' : this.model.get('id') },
    'data': { 
        'title': this.model.format('station_na'), 
        'icon': media_url + this.model._iconRootURL + 'weather-station-16x16.png'
    }
};
// Add the tree element to the end of the tree
$.jstree._reference('#irrigationClimateStations').create_node("#irrigationClimateStations", "last", newNode);
```

I haven't been able to decipher the API based on the documentation or the source code>  I've also tried creating the node using "Method 2" alluded to in the core documentation:

```
var parent = $('#irrigationClimateStations').jstree('get_selected');
$('#irrigationClimateStations').jstree("create", parent, "last", newNode, false, false);
```

Any help?  I am running jstree v 1.0-rc3

Comment: @EswarRajeshPinapala, that's not JSON! That's just an object.

Comment: Ah, I get this all the time. Sorry I was assuming that was a json text.

Comment: Looking for the same solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9410038/jstree-progressive-render-with-ajax-render-nodes-from-an-array